# Removing words comprised of upper and lowercase letters?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have file called `file.txt`. In this file there are words composed of upper and lowercase letters, also there are words consist of upper or lowercase letters and numbers. I would like to filter this file, so the output is free of the words that contain **both** upper and lower case letters. For example, the input `file.txt`:

```
Aaa
aBb
aB
Aa12
12aA
123
123Ab
AAA
aaa
```

In this file there are words with upper and lowercase letters (e.g. Aaa, aBp), and words contain upper/lower case letters *AND* digits (e.g.  123Ab). In addition, to words contain only small letters (e.g. aaa), or only capital letters (e.g. AAA). 
I would like to remove only the words that contain upper *AND* lowercase letters (e.g. Aaa, aBp), so the output is as follows:

```
Aa12
12aA
123
123Ab
AAA
aaa
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, do you mean you would like to remove capital and lowercase letters and keep digits?

Comment: This reads like homework for school?  You should at least have a try, maybe `man sed` for starters

Comment: Hi I want to keep the lines with digits , only lower, oly capital and digit with lower or capital both

Comment: Hi Goro plz help as my example output above

Comment: Please try harder to ***explain*** more clearly what you want.  I don’t understand your problem statement, and I can’t figure it out from the example.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: FWIW I found this pretty clear from the example, but I've edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: A possible solution: `grep -E '([a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -Exv '[A-Za-z]*([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])[A-Za-z]*'
```

### Explanation

- The idea is to match the opposite of what you want first, i.e. those lines that contain only upper- and lower-case letters. This uses `grep -Ex`, i.e. grep with extended regex, match the whole line. The `-v` flag then negates the regex, i.e. return those lines that *do not* match the following regex.
- The central part `([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])` matches a single upper-case letter followed by a lower-case letter, or vice versa.
- The outer part `[A-Za-z]*...[A-Za-z]*` means that the rest of the line must comprise upper- or lower-case letters only.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. If this answered your question, please click the tick on the left to accept it, and optionally upvote with the up arrow if you like.

Comment: Based on your interpretation of the question, your answer fails for inputs like ``DeF`` that begin and end with uppercase letters, but have lowercase letter(s) in the middle.

Comment: @G-Man Oops you are right. Forgot the parens. Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: Ah, so that’s what you meant. I believe that you can leave out the `+`s and simplify the command to `grep -Exv '[A-Za-z]*([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])[A-Za-z]*'`.   P.S. The OP doesn’t have the privilege to vote yet.

Comment: @G-Man Good idea. I basically built the regex from the inside (point 2), before realising I needed point 3 as well. Thanks for the advice (and the privilege info too).

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` and assuming one word per line:

```
grep -E '[[:digit:]]|^([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+)$'
```

To report all the matching words in a text, with potentially several words per lines, words delimited by non-word characters:

```
<text tr -cs '[:alnum:][:digit:]_' '[\n*]' |
  grep -E '[[:digit:]]|^([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+)$'
```

Note that you need a POSIX compliant `tr` implementation, GNU `tr` won't do. On GNU systems, you can use `sed` instead:

```
<text sed -E 's/\W+/\n/g' |
  grep -E '[[:digit:]]|^([[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

To restate your requirements, you want to *keep* a word if:

- it contains a <del>digit</del> non-letter, or
- it is all uppercase letters, or
- it is all lowercase letters

Then

```
awk '/[^[:alpha:]]/ || /^[[:upper:]]+$/ || /^[[:lower:]]+$/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -E -e '/[0-9]/b' -e '/^[A-Z]+$/b' -e '/^[a-z]+$/b' -e 'd' <file
Aa12
12aA
123
123Ab
AAA
aaa
```

Annotated `sed` script:

```
/[0-9]/b        # Digits are present, branch to end
/^[A-Z]+$/b     # Only uppercase characters present, branch to end
/^[a-z]+$/b     # Only lowercase characters present, branch to end
d               # Delete line, start next cycle
                # (at end, implicit print)
```

Alternatively,

```
sed -E -e '/[[:digit:]]/b' -e '/^[[:upper:]]+$/b' -e '/^[[:lower:]]+$/b' -e 'd' <file
```

There may be a difference between this and the first `sed` script depending on your locale.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `[A-Z]` won't match on lower case characters (or even collating elements made of several characters some of which are lower case), For instance, on Solaris 11.4, in the en_US.UTF-8 locale, `[A-Z]` matches on 759 different uppercase characters, and 846806 lower case ones (well, characters that Solaris considers lowercase, but that also includes bcd...z as they sort between A and Z). Solaris sed doesn't support -E though.